# Comparable в качестве типа данных параметра функции

Tags: java, java-8

Пишу двусвязный список, который имплементирует заранее подготовленный интерфейс. В интерфейсе есть методы вида

```
@Override
public void delete(Comparable e) {}
```

в которые передаются параметры типа `Comparable`. Как такое возможно? Разве интерфейсы не предполагают невозможность порождения от них объектов?

Comment: В этот метод можно передать любой объект имплементирующий интерфейс Comparable. А поскольку он его реализует, значит в нем есть метод описанный в интерфейсе

Comment: @Виктор Так и предполагал, однако при попытке переопределения метода возникает проблема: необходимо использовать поля объекта, чей класс реализует интерфейс Comparable, но добраться до них через оператор точка не получается

Comment: потому что интерфейс ничего не знает о полях объекта. Он даже об объекте не знает. Все, что он знает это о том, что там реализованы методы интерфейса